# Cannot filter barcode scanner result with Filterable

Tags: android, kotlin, filtering, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am having problem to filter my barcode scanner result with my filter method. I need to have both manual search and barcode search on my EditText field search. Manual searrh works fine, bur when I scan barcode, the barcode number appears inside EditText field, but it doesnt activate search method.

Filter code from MainActivity

```
search!!.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
                adapter!!.filter.filter(charSequence.toString())         
            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {}
        })
```

Barcode scanner code from MainActivity

```
    private var mScanManager: ScanManager? = null
    private var idbuf = intArrayOf(PropertyID.WEDGE_INTENT_ACTION_NAME, PropertyID.WEDGE_INTENT_DATA_STRING_TAG)
    private var actionValueBuf = arrayOf(ScanManager.ACTION_DECODE, ScanManager.BARCODE_STRING_TAG)
    private lateinit var mScanReceiver: BroadcastReceiver


 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
mScanManager = ScanManager()
        try {
            mScanManager?.openScanner()
            actionValueBuf = mScanManager!!.getParameterString(idbuf)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.w("Barcode scanner", "No barcod scanner found", e)
        }
}


 private fun Context.registerReceiver(
        intentFilter: IntentFilter, onReceive: (intent: Intent?) -> Unit
    ): BroadcastReceiver {
        val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
                onReceive(intent)
            }
        }
        this.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)
        return receiver
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val filter = IntentFilter()

        try {
            actionValueBuf = mScanManager!!.getParameterString(idbuf)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.w("Barcode scanner", "No barcod scanner found", e)
        }

        filter.addAction(actionValueBuf[0])
        mScanReceiver = registerReceiver(IntentFilter(filter)) { intent ->
            result = intent?.getStringExtra(actionValueBuf[1])
            if (result != null) {
                search?.text?.clear()
                search?.setText(result)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        unregisterReceiver(mScanReceiver)
    }
```

I have tried something like this but it doesnt work

```
search!!.requestFocus()
        search!!.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
               //result is barcode number
                if(result == null){
                    adapter!!.filter.filter(charSequence.toString())
                } else {
                    adapter!!.filter.filter((result))
                    resultLength= charSequence.toString()
                    search?.setSelection(resultLength.toString().length)
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {}
        })
```

Comment: It's not clear from your code exactly when you perform `addTextChangedListener`, and that you actually have done that before you call `setText`.

Comment: onCreate method, that is where I perform addTextChangedListener